# Quandl import error in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, quandl

I'm using Python 3.6.3 on Windows 10 and Quandl module in my pip list, but I get the following error:

```
import quandl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import quandl
  File "C:\Users\Kamal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\quandl\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .api_config import ApiConfig

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quandl.api_config'
```

Comment: Did you forget to activate an environment, by chance?

Comment: What does activating environment  means, I m new to python.. @Dan

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip3 install quandl`. If you have python2 installed, there may be a mismatch in symlinks related to pip.

Comment: Plz see the error massage once again it is importing quandl but error is in qunadl file ,as error massage says.